# Landscape only app crashes when presenting camera - Cocoa2d

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I have a game that only works on landscape mode. When I presenting camera the app crashes due to orientation problems. I solved the problem by adding the following methods in AppDelegate.

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] != UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

However it works but it changes the app to support all orientations. What I need is the app supports portrait mode only for camera. After presenting the camera the app support only landscape mode.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a temporary view controller that will be presented in portrait mode, then launch the camera modal from there.

Comment: Is it possible to create temporary view controller in cocoa2d applications